# Blockfrost and Plutus Application Backend

Tags: pab, plutus-pab

I am wondering if anyone has tried both backend services to develope smart contracts? I am aware that [IOHK's PAB](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps/tree/main/plutus-pab) is compatible only with Plutus whereas [Blockfrost's API](https://blockfrost.io/) allows to use other programming languages to build the [off-chain part of dApps](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W2R3zl91U24&t=233s).

Can someone share their experience with either option?

Answer (score 0):

The reference implementation most projects are using is the Spacebudz project which uses of Nami Wallet dapp connector, smart contract and blockfrost.

https://github.com/Berry-Pool/spacebudz

We're using something similar and have not encountered any issues.